# When making bread, is it possible to freeze the dough?

Tags: baking, freezing, flatbread

I like to make flatbreads but have minimal space for kneading/making the dough, which requires a lot of effort to move away kitchen items and machines. The recipe I usually do uses yeast with about 1 hour of proofing time.

What I would like to do is make a large batch of dough and preferably freeze them in portions to defrost, roll out and bake in a frying pan.

I figured since they are flatbreads, it might not matter that much, but what effects can this have on the dough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, dough can be frozen, later thawed and continue making bread. There is, in general, no effect on the dough/yeast once it's thawed/re-warmed. Freezing them relatively flat will help them to freeze/thaw faster than as more rounded (ball or log) shapes.

An alternative (not one I use or particularly suggest, but you might want to know it exists) is to "[par-bake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parbaking)" breads and store them frozen. In that case you can pull from the freezer and bake, since you've already let it rise and "set" the structure by par-baking before freezing. This is common in commercial baking (for, *e.g.* restaurant supply) to allow "freshly baked bread" without anything other than the final baking being done on-premises. They do take up more freezer space.

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much for your answer. I usually par-bake but that isn't really viable for flatbreads.